# Grabbing iPhone screenWidth and Height for reusability

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I created a category like so:

```
#import "UIViewController+Dimensions.h"

@implementation UIView (Dimensions)

- (double) screenWidth2
{
    return self.frame.size.width;
}

- (double) screenHeight2
{
    return self.frame.size.height;
}


@end
```

But when I try to call it in my view controller after importing it, I get:

```
"Use of undeclared identifier screenWidth2;
```

Is there a better way to grab the screenWidth in one place then every view controller I'm in?

I then did this in my view controller:

```
 _registerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [self screenWidth2] / 2.0 - 1.0, 60.0);
```

but the app compiles runs and crashes.  And the category's .h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (Dimensions)

- (double) screenWidth2;

- (double) screenHeight2;

@end
```

Comment: are you sure you declared `- (double) screenWidth2` method in `Category's` `.h` file also?

Comment: As an aside. 1) you should use a prefix for methods you provide in categories for system classes. 2) you should be using CGFloat instead of double for the return value, particularly now that some iOS devices will be running in 64-bit environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
#import "UIViewController+Dimensions.h"
```

In the code using the category (the file where you call [uiViewControllerInstance screenWidth2])

Comment: the [self screenWidth2] needed to be added and I changed from UIView to UIViewController and missed one spot

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that those variables are declared in the .h? So, they are public.

Also, to use the category, add this:

```
#import "UIViewController+Dimensions.h"
```

In the class that have to use the category.

Comment: I have that declared correctly, but I try to do this:   _registerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [self screenWidth2] / 2.0 - 1.0, 60.0); the app crashes